# What's the difference between Full and FullRebuild in JS add-ins for Excel 365?

Tags: office365, office-js, excel-addins, office-store

We want to use context.application.calculate(Excel.CalculationType.full).
What's the difference between Full and FullRebuild? Namely, what does "This will rebuild the full dependency chain" mean?
(link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.calculationtype?view=excel-js-preview)

Comment: From the documentation you linked, "Full" consists of two phases, while "FullRebuild" the same two phases preceded by "This will rebuild the full dependency chain". I would interpret this first phase as "Analyzing all formulas in the sheet again and see which depends on which cells". This would then be used as a plan in which order the cells need to be re-calculated. Hence, "Full" would rely on the dependency information cached in the sheet, while "FullRebuild" would throw away the currently cached dependency information and re-create it as a first step.